# Ethernet not working Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ethernet, home-networking

I've been setting up a new homeserver and so far I have not been able to make it work properly. I want to use the Ethernet cable I've used before, but Ubuntu (18.04) is not using it correctly / at all.

Here's some of the info:

```
lshw -c network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:19:99:c2:e6:e6
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=1.0-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:ce520000-ce53ffff ioport:4000(size=32) memory:ce500000-ce503fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:1
       logical name: wlx000cf660daa1
       serial: 00:0c:f6:60:da:a1
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=4.15.0-54-generic firmware=0.36 ip=192.168.178.100 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

```
ifconfig
enp7s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:19:99:c2:e6:e6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xce520000-ce540000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 16  bytes 1616 (1.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16  bytes 1616 (1.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx000cf660daa1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        ether 00:0c:f6:60:da:a1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2981  bytes 525689 (525.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 177  bytes 35551 (35.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp7s0:
      dhcp4: yes
  wifis:
    wlx000cf660daa1:
      dhcp4: yes
      addresses: [192.168.178.100/24]
```

Here are some of the things I have tried/done over the past 2 days:

- Check if the Ethernet cable is good (it is)
- Try multiple different netplan configurations (DHCP on/off, static IP, etc.)
- Update Ubuntu in an effort to see if new drivers would get installed.

I've read a lot of forum posts on askubuntu and some questions here and have still not been able to get through this.
There is a wireless dongle in the server for now so I can access it from my other pc and such :)